# How can I generalize a Hashmap type in Java?

Tags: java

I would like to generalize the result that I return from within a function of my application. Currently I return a Hashmap as a result and parse that into the UI, showing it to the user.

I want to extend the values that my application returns. Quick example:

```
    public class Model implements Runnable {
        private HashMap<String, Integer> result;
        public HashMap<String, Integer> returntheanswertoeverything() {
            HashMap<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<String, Integer>(result.putall(answer(universe));
// returns (universe,42)

            return result;
            }
    }
```

With result returning the hashmap along with my results. In a seperate function or GUI I can output this to the user. However if I want to not just return an integer, but additional stuff, how would I do that best?

If I wanted to return for the universe a third(fourth ...) answer? How would I keep this extendable?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you post a sample example showing what you are trying to do?

Comment: Don't return maps. Return objects. Java is an OO language.

Comment: Please use obey the name convention even in your example 'returnTheAnswerToEverything()' and @JBNizet what you mean return an object, now return a HashMap and this is object too, I couldn't understand what you mean?

Comment: ok, the way to go is apparently to refactor the integer from the hashmap into an object. is this easily possible in eclipse? for an example i would be most grateful

Comment: What I mean is that if the method is supposed to return information about a user, it should return an instance of the class `User`. If it must return information about the universe, it should return an instance of the class `Universe`. Use OO, with well-defined typed fields, methods, encapsulation, polymorphism.

Comment: @tarrasch: you still haven't explained what you wanted to do. And I'm pretty sure the way to go is not to refactor the integer into an object. The way to go is (probably) to return something other than a HashMap: a real object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return additional info besides the `Integer`, create a wrapper class where you store your data, and put that into your `Map`.

```
public YourAdditionalInfoClass {

    // Up to you if you want getter/setters or just public visibility
    public Integer yourIntegerValue;

    // Replace Object by the additional class you want
    public Object yourAdditionalInfo;
}

public HashMap<String, YourAdditionalInfoClass > returntheanswertoeverything()
```